# How to filter the data according to name and title in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am trying to filter the data  according to name and title but its not working. I have tried all the scenario but its not working. Please help me to find out the solution. I am getting all the data in list but unable to filter data according to name and title.Here is my json data so please help me to solve this problem thankyou in advance.

```
{
    "0": {
        "data": {
            "_id": 0,
            "prefix": "Male",
            "firstname": "prem",
            "lastname": "Karn1",
            "phone": "23424242424",
            "email": "karnprem@cronj.com",
            "__v": 0,
            "zones": [
                "0"
            ]
        },
        "title": "Logistic Agent"
    }
}

<div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">by Name</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText.data.firstname">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">by Zone</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">by Title</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="title">
                                        <option value="">All</option>
                                        <option value="">Zone Manager</option>
                                        <option value="">Logistic agent</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 control-label">by Business Value</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                                    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body form-group-separated">
                    <div class="table-responsive" >
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="searchObjResults" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Telephone</th>        
                                    <th>Email Address</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr  ng-repeat="accDetails in acct_list  | filter:searchText">
                                    <td>
                                      <img src="/assets/img/a0.jpg" alt="User pic" height="30" width="30">
                                    </td>

                                    <td>{{accDetails.data.firstname}}</td>
                                    <td>{{accDetails.data.lastname}}</td>
                                    <td>{{accDetails.title}}</td>
                                    <td>{{accDetails.data.phone}}</td>
                                    <td>{{accDetails.data.email}}</td
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                        </table> 
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is My Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/BGOPyQ7c3v5qNASk5Kg7?p=preview

Comment: Can you create a plunkr/fiddle for the same?

Comment: your are making mistake.

Comment: tell me what is the mistake?

Comment: Hi V31 i have shared plnkr please see where's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter the data in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164921/how-to-filter-the-data-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText.data.firstname">


<tr  ng-repeat="accDetails in acct_list  | filter:searchText"> </tr>   //don't bind searchText only rather

<tr  ng-repeat="accDetails in acct_list  | filter:searchText.data.firstname"></tr> //This will work only for firstname
```

for multiple criteria use more pipe filters....

Comment: Oh seriously !? now please provide me jsfiddle so i can help you further if possible with less code.

Comment: Hi micronys i am giving you plnkr for this problem please see where's  the problem?