# How to filter the data in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am trying to filter the data according to `firstname` and `title` properties but it's not filtering.

```
<label>by Name 
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText.data.firstname"></label> |

<label>by Title
  <select name="title">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="">Zone Manager</option>
    <option value="">Logistic agent</option>
  </select></label>

<hr/>

<div ng-repeat="accDetails in acct_list | filter:searchText">
   {{accDetails.data.firstname}} |
   {{accDetails.data.lastname}} | 
   {{accDetails.title}}

</div>
```

The JSON data is:

```
$scope.acct_list = {
  "0": {
    "data": {
        "firstname": "maeli",
        "lastname": "mad",
        //...
    },
    "title": "Shop"
  },
  "1": {
    "data": {
        //...
    },
    "title": "hotel"
  }
}
```

Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RE1f26pUkT1ihG9LCQbR?p=preview)

Comment: Must we see all the styling and the markup to understand your question in full? You want people here to help you - help us by cleaning irrelevant parts of the code you post. Read this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you can see plnkr if you can solve the problem

Comment: I have removed irrelevant parts from your question to make it easier for people to help you. Please invest time next time you post a question.

Comment: okk Thanks for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that filtering doesn't work is because `filter` only works on arrays, and your `acct_list` is not an array.

You can either change your data to an array:

```
$scope.acct_list = [
  {
    "data": {
        "firstname": "maeli",
        "lastname": "mad",
        //...
    },
    "title": "Shop"
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

or, arrange into an array in the controller and `ng-repeat` over that.

Here's another relevant [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs) on this topic.

Also, don't forget to add `ng-model="searchText.title"` to your `<select>` and fill-in the `<option>` values accordingly.